# Where do I write the verb at the present tense?

Tags: verb

Should I write, for the verb:

> Am Morgen hat Lisa Frühdienst

or:

> Am Morgen Lisa hat Frühdienst

We are talking of what Lisa usually do in the morning. ("Lisa ist Krankenschwester", by the way...)
Does it change the sense?

Comment: Do you mean really _Am Morgen = in the morning_ or _Morgen = tomorrow_?

Comment: @Iris Am Morgen: in the morning!

Comment: But if you are speaking the 2nd way to someone the person would probably understand. :)

Comment: @Marine1 Unless you were talking about an unusual kind of establishment, specifying FRÜHdienst in the sentence would make little sense. Normally, Frühdienst is done in the morning. Therefore everyone assumed you were talking about tomorrow.

Comment: Ludi, yes, I'm talking about tommorrow! I'm editing.

Comment: Are you sure you want to put my question on hold as far as G.S has only 6 question a day and that a site with 5 questions or fewer per day needs some work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first version is correct, the second is not. You have to put the verb, *hat*, in second position when counting parts of speech. The first is *Am Morgen*.

Comment: Or you could say: "Lisa hat am Morgen Frühdienst"

Comment: @Iris Or "Frühdienst hat Lisa am Morgen". The key thing is mentioned in the answer: "you have to put the verb in second position".